# Is it possible generate clientid and client_secret key for a perticular folder in Sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint

1. is it possible to generate clientid and client_secret key for a perticular folder in Sharepoint site ?
   as we do not want to open whole site access to the user ?.
   if yes please provide me the procedure .
2. we need to edit an excel tracker present in the SharePoint folder , how we can do that using python
   automation ?

Thanks
suvendu

Answer (score 0):

The minimum permission scope for sharepoint app is List scope. It's impossible to  to generate clientid and client_secret for folder level.

You could refer to this article for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint#types-of-add-in-permissions-and-permission-scopes